# How to implement the method CanToProlong in an interface IProlongable (deposits)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# task in which you need to create an interface IProlongable (renewal of the deposit) and declare the `CanToProlong` method in it without parameters that return a boolean value true or false, depending on whether this particular deposit can be extended or not. Here is its complete
condition:

**Task :**

To add the following new functionalities to the project created in task 7:

1. To create interface `IProlongable` (prolonging deposit) and declare within it method `CanToProlong` without parameters that returns logic value true or false, depending on the fact whether this specific deposit can be prolonged or not.
2. To implement interface `IProlongable` in classes `SpecialDeposit` and `LongDeposit`.
3. In addition, special deposit (`SpecialDeposit`) can be prolonged only when more than 1000 UAH were deposited, and long-term deposit (`LongDeposit`) can be prolonged if the period of deposit is no longer than 3 years.
4. To implement standard generic interface IComparable < Deposit> in abstract class Deposit. Total sum amount (sum deposited plus interest during the entire period) should be considered as comparison criteria of Deposit instances.
5. To implement additionally in class Client:

   • Interface `IEnumerable` .

   • Method `SortDeposits`, which performs deposits sorting in array deposits in descending order of total sum amount on deposit upon deposit expiration.

   • Method `CountPossibleToProlongDeposit`, which returns integer – amount of current client’s deposits that can be prolonged.

when implemented, my code throws an error. I ask for help in writing the code. I'm new to C#. This is what I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Interfaces
{
    public interface IProlongable
    {
        bool CanToProlong();
    }

    public bool CanToProlong()
    {
        int count = default;
        IEnumerable<object> deposits = null;
        foreach (var deposit in deposits)
        {
            object CanToProlong = null;
            if (deposit is IProlongable p && !CanToProlong)

            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: if that is all the code above, then you need to get back to learning about interfaces and how to use them :-D ... HINT: something ... like a ```class``` needs to implement your interface

Answer (score 0):

You have got a homework at your hands. A lot depends on what was asked in Task 7 of your homework.

Here's some code to get you started for now, based on what I could make sense so far:

```
 interface IProlongable
   {
      bool CanToProlong();
   }

   class Deposit : IProlongable, IComparable<Deposit>
   {
      protected decimal _Balance;

      public decimal Balance
      {
         get => _Balance;
         private set => _Balance = value;
      }

      protected float _DurationInYears;

      public float DurationInYears
      {
         get => _DurationInYears;
         private set => _DurationInYears = value;
      }

      public virtual bool CanToProlong()
      {
         return false;
      }

      public int CompareTo(Deposit other)
      {
         return this.Balance.CompareTo(other.Balance);
      }

      public Deposit(decimal openingBalance, float durationYears)
      {
         _Balance = openingBalance;
         _DurationInYears = durationYears;
      }
   }

   class SpecialDeposit : Deposit
   {
      public SpecialDeposit(): base(0, 0)
      {

      }

      public SpecialDeposit(decimal openingBalance, float durationYears) : base(openingBalance, durationYears)
      {

      }

      public override bool CanToProlong()
      {
         if (Balance > 1000)
            return true;

         return false;
      }
   }

   class LongDeposit : Deposit
   {
      public LongDeposit() : base(0, 0)
      {

      }

      public LongDeposit(decimal openingBalance, float durationYears) : base(openingBalance, durationYears)
      {

      }

      public override bool CanToProlong()
      {
         if (DurationInYears <= 3)
            return true;

         return false;
      }
   }
```

In Addition to this, you should have some additional stuff in Deposit class that helps you calculate Interest/Expiries etc.
And you should have a Client class which quiet possibly has an array of Deposit as a Data Member. This Client class should exhibit some additional Sorting features as asked for in the last part of your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Task
To create classes Deposit (bank account), BaseDeposit (regular deposit), SpecialDeposit (special deposit), LongDeposit (long-term deposit), Client (bank client) with set functionality.
To create abstract class Deposit and declare within it:
• Public money property only for reading Amount (deposit amount)
• Public integer property only for reading Period (time of deposit in months)
• Constructor (for calling in class-inheritor) with parameters depositAmount
and depositPeriod, which creates object deposit with specified sum for
specified period.
• Abstract method Income, which returns money value – amount of income
from deposit. Income is the difference between sum, withdrawn from deposit upon expiration date and deposited sum.
To create classes that are inheritors of the class Deposit, which determine different options of deposit interest addition – class BaseDeposit, class SpecialDeposit and class LongDeposit. To implement in each class a constructor with parameters amount and period, which calls constructor of parent class.
For each inheritor class – to implement own interest addition scheme and accordingly profit margin definitions, overriding abstract method Income in each class.
BaseDeposit implies each month 5% of interest from current deposit sum. Each following month of income is calculated from the sum, which was received by adding to current income sum of the previous month and is rounded to hundredth.
Example: Base amount – 1000,00
In a month – 105,00; income amount – 50,00
In two months – 1102,50; income amount – 102,50 In three months – 1157,62; income amount – 157,62
SpecialDeposit implies income addition each month, amount of which (in percent) equals to deposit expiration period. If during the first month 1% is added, during the second month – 2% from the sum obtained after first month and so on.

Example: Base amount – 1000,00
In a month – 1010,00; income amount – 10,00
In two months – 1030,20; income amount – 30,20
LongDeposit implies that during first 6 months, no percent is added to client’s deposit, but starting from 7th month, each month percent addition is 15% from current deposit sum, thus encouraging client to make long-term deposits.
To create class Client (bank client) and declare within it:
• Private field deposits (client deposits) – objects array of type Deposit
• Constructor without parameters, which creates empty array deposits
consisting of 10 elements
• Method AddDeposit with parameter deposit for adding regular, special or
long-term account into array on the first empty spot and returning true, or returning false, if accounts number limit is depleted (no empty space in array).
• Method TotalIncome, returning total income amount based on all client’s deposits upon deposits expiration.
• Method MaxIncome, returning maximum deposit income of all client’s deposits upon deposits expiration.
• Method GetIncomeByNumber with integer parameter number (deposit number, which equals its index in array, increased by one), returning income from deposit with such number. If deposit with such number does not exist, method returns 0 value.

Comment: this is the last task you asked about

Answer (score 0):

```
add my code for the rest of the files

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Interfaces
{
    public class Client : IComparable
    {
        private readonly Deposit[] deposits;

        public Client()
        {
            deposits = new Deposit[10];
        }
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return 1;
            Client otherClient = obj as Client;
            if (otherClient != null)
            {
                if (TotalIncome() > otherClient.TotalIncome()) return 1;
                else
                if (TotalIncome() < otherClient.TotalIncome()) return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a client");
        }
        public decimal TotalIncome()
        {
            decimal sum = 0m;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (deposits[i] != null)
                {
                    sum += deposits[i].Income();
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }

        public interface IEnumerable
        {
            IEnumerator Deposit();
        }


        public void SortDeposits()
        {
            Array.Sort(deposits, (x, y) => Comparer<Deposit>.Default.Compare(y, x));
        }

        public int CountPossibleToProlongDeposit()
        {
            var count = 0;
            foreach (var item in deposits)
            {
                if (item is IProlongable ip && ip.CanToProlong())
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }

    }
}`enter code here`

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Interfaces
{
    public abstract class Deposit : IComparable<Deposit> 
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; }
        public int Period { get; }
        public int CompareTo(Deposit other) 
        {
            return Amount.CompareTo(other.Amount);
        }
        public Deposit(decimal depositAmount, int depositPeriod)
        {
            Amount = depositAmount;
            Period = depositPeriod;
        }
        public abstract decimal Income();
    }
}`
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Interfaces
{
    //TODO: Use class "BaseDeposit" from previous task ("Aggregation").
    class BaseDeposit : Deposit
    {
        public readonly decimal amount;
        public readonly int period;
        public BaseDeposit(decimal amount, int period) : base(amount, period)
        {
            this.amount = amount;
            this.period = period;
        }

        public override decimal Income()
        {
            return Calc(amount, 5m, period);
        }

        decimal Calc(decimal amount, decimal percent, int period)
        {
            return amount * Power((1m + percent / 100m), period)
            - amount; 
        }

        decimal Power(decimal x, int pow)
        {
            var r = 1m;
            for (var i = 0; i < pow; i++)
                r *= x;
            return r;
        }
    }

}`enter code here`

    enter code here
```